# Can the focused part of Visual Studio Code be outlined?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I avoid using the mouse for navigation as much as possible. Sometimes when I go back into VSCode via spotlight/raycast the focus will be on some element in the sidebar, or the terminal, or the vim cursor is just immediately obvious. Is there a way to enable some sort of obvious outline on the part of the UI that currently has focus so further navigation can be easier? I perused the settings but didn't see one that immediately stood out.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76980603/836330

Currently it is as close as you are going to get to making it more clear which editor or terminal has focus.  The unfocused editors/terminal can be dimmed.

---

You can change the usual blue focus border (like you get with tabbing around the window elements) to another color, like red, with this setting in your `settings.json`:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "focusBorder": "#ff0000"
}
```

For some elements like those that border on the window edge it doesn't help much.  For others it helps.

Comment: thanks, this helps to some degree as I did have issues seeing the border in sidebar elements, however this doesn't solve the issue of knowing which "window" of the UI is open. For example: which editor group is currently in focus, or if none of them are in focus and the terminal is. This is a fairly edge case, as it usually only is a problem if I'm refocusing my VSCode window after being in another application, but seeing that distinct red border around the terminal or editor group element in the UI would shave a couple seconds off of recognition here and there.

Comment: I looked through the `colorCustomizations` for `focus` and there isn't much that is helpful.